# Unable to select from hive table with custom inputformat

Tags: hadoop, hive, cloudera

We have developed custom input format to process edi files. After the recent upgrade to 5.8, select * from table doesn't return any rows.

Hive script:

```
*create external table CustomInputTest
(
  all_cols String
)
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 'parser.mapred.X12InputFormat'
OUTPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
LOCATION '/user/data/EDI'
TBLPROPERTIES ('edi.schema.hdfs.path' = '/user/data/layout/edi.xsl');*

*set hive.input.format=org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveInputFormat;

 select * from CustomInputTest;*
```

The same script returns expected output on Hive 1.1.0-cdh5.4.9.

on CDH 5.8, if the hive fetch task is disabled to force the query to generate MapReduce, the select query is working fine.

```
*set hive.fetch.task.conversion=none*;
```

I've checked hive server logs, i don't see any errors.
How to fix the issue, such that hive fetch task works in the new version[5.8]